# TemplateSyntaxError after migrating to python 2.7

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, python-2.7, indexing

I am migrating from python2.5 to python 2.7 and am having problems with database indexes. The main page is properly generated, but I can't do any operation with the database (add an entry) without getting this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /new

Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'views.edit' with 
arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Request Method: GET

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError

Exception Value:    
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'views.edit' with 
arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Exception Location: /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/
GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-
1.2/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 385


Template error

In template /.../templates/item.html, error at line 5
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'views.edit' with 
arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Here's what I have at Line 5:

```
<form action="{%url views.edit item.key.id%}" method="post">
```

My urls.py contains:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    (r'^$', 'views.index'), 
    (r'^new$', 'views.new'), 
    (r'^edit/(\d+)$', 'views.edit'), 
)
```

It worked fine with python 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the error is because `item.key.id` is currently equal to an empty string, which is not matching your url pattern.

Instead of:

```
(r'^edit/(\d+)$', 'views.edit'),
```

try:

```
(r'^edit/(\d*)$', 'views.edit'),
```

Comment: Should this be changed?                                    urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    (r'^$', 'views.index'),
    (r'^new$', 'views.new'),
    (r'^edit/(\d+)$', 'views.edit'),
    )

Comment: It's really going to depend, but if you change the '+' in your edit pattern to '*', then it will match. As for if that will solve your problem totally, I'm not sure.